# Devise issue Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get Devise working. I'm following this tutorial which tells me to do "rails generate devise User" but when I do that command, it gives me an error saying

```
"NameError: uninitialized constant User     from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2503:in `const_missing'"
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.8.7 and Ubuntu 11.04

Thanks a bunch in advance,
Michael.

Comment: Have you installed Devise using `gem install devise`? Try running `rails g -h`. Are the devise generators included in the output?

Comment: Have you run `rails g devise:install`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have `gem devise` in your Gemfile? Then, run `bundle install`. You can also try putting `require 'devise'` in your config/application.rb file (but you shouldn't have to do this).

Comment: I'm still without any kind of success. Same error, tried everything that has been suggested.

Comment: Hmm, you may try uninstalling and reinstalling the devise gem. It sounds like something has gotten messed up. Also, does it do this on a fresh rails app, or just this one?